# CSV into JSON convert

Tags: javascript, json, function, d3.js

I have a csv file in the format:

```
"","Sequence","Paths","sequence_length"
"1","Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social",29,8
"2","Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social",30,7
"3","Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social",40,6
"4","Social -> Social -> Social -> Social -> Social",71,5
"5","Social -> Social -> Social -> Social",156,4
"6","Social -> Social -> Social",273,3
"7","Social -> Social -> SEO",40,3
"8","Social -> Social",729,2
"9","Social -> SEO -> Social",51,3
"10","Social -> SEO",180,2
"11","Social -> SEM",56,2
```

I want to convert this into a JSON tree hierarchy as follows:

```
"Root" : [
    {
        "Sequence" : "Social",
        "children" : [
            {
                "Sequence" : "Social",
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "Sequence" : "Social",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "Sequence" : "Social",
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "Sequence" : "Social",
                                        "children" : [
                                            {
                                                "Sequence" : "Social",
                                                "children" : [
                                                    {
                                                        "Sequence" : "Social",
                                                        "children" : [
                                                            {
                                                                "Sequence" : "Social",
                                                                "Path" : 29}],
                                                            }
                                                        }
```

Where Each Touch Point viz. 'Social' represented by -> in CSV file at each line represents the child of the previous and the Paths is added to the last node.

I am trying to split the Social things in one array as

```
data.forEach(function(d){
var x =  d.Sequence.split(' -> ');
```

and then using the this x to parse into JSON.Could anyone please help me with it.Thanks !

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: when executed anonymous function returns, `undefined`. You might want to return function inside anonymous function to execute it next time.

Comment: @Guybrush .  self.createIframe(url);

Comment: @shivamGupta could you please exemplify, I am pretty new to this.thanks

Comment: what is purpose of creating `trackSQ` and `masterTag` as anonymous function?

Comment: I've an idea and test it for a minute. It seems, that you cannot call the method `masterTag` *before* you have created the whole object since `adserver` is not created yet and `masterTag` has not the right scope.

Comment: @Guybrush What do you suggest then should I call the masterTag outside the adserver object.Like adserver.masterTag('hkj','skjad'); removing it as IIFE

Comment: Yes, I think that is the more sound way (cf. the answer post). Maybe you create a JS *"class"* for your object?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you already call your anonymous function `masterTag` during the definition of the object. In this case, the function you assign to `masterTag` is not a function of `adserver`, it is a simple value assignment. And when that function is called during the object creation, it has not the right scope, i.e., `this` is not the `adserver` object.

E.g., this will work:

```
var adserver = {
  createIframe : function (url) {
    console.log(url);
  },
  trackSQ: (function () { })(),
  masterTag: (function (type,cat) {
    var self = this;
    self.createIframe("test");
  })
}
```

when you call

```
adserver.masterTag("targe0","maste0");
```

(I have changed your code a little bit to a minimal example)